# Spring - Hibernate Jackson mapping

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, jackson, jackson2

i have two entites building a Many-To-Many relationship, on the one side

Category.java:

```
@ManyToMany()
@JoinTable(
    name = "categories_articles",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "categoryID", referencedColumnName = "id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "articleID", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<Article>();
```

on the othder side Article.java:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "articles")
private List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();
```

plus getters and setters..

When i load in browser i get exception:

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role ... JsonMappingException
```

Is there anybody who could help me with this issue?

Shall i write my own serializer?

thanks and greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are accessing your Object outside the Hibernate Session object, so:

- add `@JsonIgnore` under `@ManyToMany` annotation

or

- add `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` - this load items from DB

You can try also `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)` instead of `early fetch`

Comment: FetchType.EAGER didnt help anything and jsonignore causes that additional data are not being loaded... i just want the data related to this entity to load as childs..

Comment: Try to add`fetch` only on `categories`.

Comment: yes i added it only on the one side and @JsonIgnore on the other side to prevent circular loading...but when i now call /articles, i dont get the associated categories... is it really that difficult?

Comment: Updated, try `@LazyCollection` on articles 'early fetch'.

Comment: still jsonmapexception.. and there is literally no literature about how to work with hibernate 5 and many-to-many relations with Rest (jackson) !

Comment: Can you add what exactly are you loading in your browser? What use case? Load of one article and its categories?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138568/discussion-between-creative-crypter-and-matej-marconak).

Answer (score 0):

A very Simple Solution would be to use **`@Transactional`** annotation on top of your service layer method, which keeps the session open till the end of the execution.